# Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: No NameTypeIndex match for SHORT_STANDARD

Tags: java, android, crash, assertion

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: No NameTypeIndex match for SHORT_STANDARD
       at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl$ZNames.getNameTypeIndex(TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:724)
       at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl$ZNames.getName(TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:790)
       at android.icu.impl.TimeZoneNamesImpl.getTimeZoneDisplayName(TimeZoneNamesImpl.java:183)
       at android.icu.text.TimeZoneNames.getDisplayName(TimeZoneNames.java:261)
       at java.util.TimeZone.getDisplayName(TimeZone.java:405)
       at java.util.Date.toString(Date.java:1066)
       at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2827)
       at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:132)
       at com.android.myplex.ui.sun.activities.SplashActivity.checkDeviceRegDetails(SplashActivity.java:798)
       at com.android.myplex.ui.sun.activities.SplashActivity.continueWithDevCalls(SplashActivity.java:536)
       at com.android.myplex.ui.sun.activities.SplashActivity.access$600(SplashActivity.java:148)
       at com.android.myplex.ui.sun.activities.SplashActivity$11.onResponse(SplashActivity.java:600)
       at com.myplex.api.APIRequest.onResponse(APIRequest.java:25)
       at com.myplex.api.request.user.UserConsentUrl$1.onResponse(UserConsentUrl.java:62)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:867)
```

Crash found in Android 8